# Using Crypto-js library with Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cryptojs

I am building a user register/login functionality and I cannot seem to encrypt the data.

Please see below the code from Express:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

var mysql = require('mysql');
var cryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

const dbConfig = require("../db.config.js");

var pool = mysql.createPool({
host: dbConfig.HOST,
user: dbConfig.USER,
password: dbConfig.PASSWORD,
database: dbConfig.DB
});

pool.getConnection(function (error, connection) {
if (error) throw error;
console.log("Successfully connected to the database.");
});

router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
const user = req.body.user;
const email = req.body.email;
const passwordOne = req.body.passwordOne;
const passwordTwo = req.body.passwordTwo;

function usernameIsValid(username) {
    return /^[0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+$/.test(username);
}

var today;
today = new Date();
today = today.getUTCFullYear() + '-' +
    ('00' + (today.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
    ('00' + today.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' +
    ('00' + today.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ':' +
    ('00' + today.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' +
    ('00' + today.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);

if (!usernameIsValid(user)) {
    console.log('error');
} else if (user.length < 3) {
    console.log('error');
} else if (passwordOne !== passwordTwo) {
    console.log('error');
} else {

    let password = passwordOne;

    var key = "abcd";
    var data = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, key); // Encryption Part
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    console.log(data);
    console.log(decrypted);
    
    let sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO `users` ( `username`, `email`, `password`, `date` ) VALUES ( '" + user + "', '" + email + "', '" + data + "', '" + today + "' )";

    pool.query(sqlInsert, function (eroare, insertul, fields) {

        if (eroare) throw eroare;
        const results = {}
        results.user = user
        results.email = email
        res.json(results);
    
    });        

}
})

module.exports = router;
```

For any reason, when I run the POST , I get the following error message :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Full error from the network tab is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body><h1>CryptoJS is not defined</h1><h2></h2><pre>ReferenceError: CryptoJS is not defined
at D:\Work\face\facesReact\api\routes\register.js:51:20
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Work\face\facesReact\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\Work\face\facesReact\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\Work\face\facesReact\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Work\face\facesReact\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at D:\Work\face\facesReact\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (D:\Work\face\facesReact\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\Work\face\facesReact\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (D:\Work\face\facesReact\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
at router (D:\Work\face\facesReact\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)</pre></body></html>
```

I am unsure how to proceed further as this should have worked.
If I remove the encryption functionality, everything works fine, it does not break.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, easy typo mistake, I guess I was too tired when writing this, I am just going to post for people to see the mistake.

The mistake was that the library was imported as: cryptoJS and it was later used as CryptoJS, notice the capitalization.